# Querying using Lambda Expression for exists within a list

Tags: c#, linq

In my project, I need to return a list of car data that does not match the model Id' provided in the array. I'm unsure on how I would go in getting my query to work. So far i have the following below:

```
var IdList = new List<int> { 60,61,62, 63, 64, 65 };
var query = Context.ManufacturersTable.Where(m => m.Date == date && m.CountryToship = country && m.ExportOnly == false);
if(query.Count() > 0)
    query = query.Where(x => x.CarMoreInfoTable.CarModelTable.Where(f => IdList.Contains(f.ModelId))) //Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type error here

return query
```

As you can see in the above query I have 3 tables all linked to each other.  But please could some direct me on how I would query all data that does not contain the Id's in the given array?

Thank you

Comment: try with `query.Where(x => x.CarMoreInfoTable.CarModelTable.Any(f => !IdList.Contains(f.ModelId)))`, Point of contention use usage of inner `Where()`

Comment: if I've understood this correctly, could you do `f => !IdList.Contains(f.ModelId)`?

Comment: Only just noticed that you put an error message in a comment at the end of a line that is out of view. Might be better to put that message in the body of the post so it can be seen without scroll bars.

Comment: Could you please describe the cardinality of the relationships?

Answer (score 2):

You have an error because second 'Where' is the issue here, first Where expects to delegate method return bool instead of IEnumerable. (Comment edit) And I think you have to negate:

`IdList.Contains(f.ModelId)`

**Edit**

If you need Car Data (I will assume that it is inside CarModel class) then you need change first Where to SelectMany (we would like to merge many collections into one) and negate the inner expression (with contains).

```
var result = query
.SelectMany(x => x.CarMoreInfoTable.CarModelTable
                  .Where(f => !IdList.Contains(f.ModelId))).ToList();
```

Comment: won't that omit all  `CarModelTable` items even if only one of them is in `IdList`

Comment: @DaveBecker I Edited my answer